# Update Visual Studio 2017 to Preview version

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Does anyone know if it is possible to update from Visual Studio 2017 to Preview version?
I don't want to install one more visual studio instance or reinstall existing one.

Comment: Just uninstall your current 2017 version and install the Preview afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's meant to be separate.

From https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/preview/

> Side-by-Side
>
> Preview installs next to your stable Visual Studio IDE, allowing you to use either independently